# How does one store docker layers outside a minikube's hyperkit vm?

Tags: docker, minikube, hyperkit

So if I create a minikube cluster on my local laptop, with a hyperkit vm:

How can I save the downloaded docker layers such that if I delete the minikube hyperkit vm, can I create a new vm, and not have to redownload all those layers.

This could be some guidance on how to create and restore the docker containers on that vm, or a way to construct the vm such that the downloaded docker containers are stored outside the vm. I'm not 100% certain what the best approach would be. Other than watching containers I just spent time downloading re-download brings sadness.